# Calling a Django Function upon an html button click

Tags: python, html, django, button, view

I'm trying to create a function where when an html button is clicked, the "coins" a profile has is incremented by 10.

Here's my html

```
<div class="sideContainer" id="buttonNav">
  <span class="redButton">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="buttonRed" name = "redButton">  <a  href="{% url 'redButton' %}"> Red </a>
 </button>
</span>


</div>
```

Here's my view

```
@login_required
def Red(request):
    Profile.coins += 10
    return(request, "home/home.html")
```

Here's my profile model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coins = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)



    def __str__(self):
        # @ts-ignore
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

And Here is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('redButton/', views.Red, name='redButton'),
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, get profile object from the current object. Here, I used `get_object_or_404`. Then, increased the `coins` value of the profile by 10 in next line. Then, updated profile coins.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

@login_required
def Red(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    profile.coins += 10
    profile.save(update_fields=['coins']
    return render(request, "home/home.html")
```